# Get all selected rows by shift click

Tags: java, swing, jtable, click

If I have a `JTable` in java and if I click on the first row then shift+click lets say on the 10th row, how would get all the selected rows between 1 and 10... Is there a code for it? thanks in advance

Comment: This answer details how allow multiple selections: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2510009/3457142

Answer (score 2):

> how would get all the selected rows

Check out the JTable API. You can use the `getSelectedRows()` method to get the indexes of all the selected rows. Then you write a loop to iterate through the indexes to access the data that you need.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're asking for is the method [JTable.setSelectionMode(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setSelectionMode(int)), using as parameter [ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html#SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION) or possibly [ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html#MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION), to enable the selection of multiple contiguous rows. For instance:

```
JTable table = ...;
table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
```